# Javascript to fix invalid html?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, wysiwyg

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a javascript tool that can automatically fix invalid html syntax? I'm working on a javascript based in-place editor, but I don't yet have an elegant solution to prevent bad nesting like this:

```
<p><span></p></span>
```

I was wondering if a script might already exist that can take invalid html and return it cleaned up automatically? Is there anything like that already out there, or am I going to have to solve this problem myself?

Comment: [Markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Enter your URI, and then hit `More Options`, and select `Clean up markup with HTML-Tidy`, and voila. However, this might mess up other things that you're doing, so I recommend you go through these yourself

Answer (score 1):

Pippin's comment about [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) was exactly what I needed. For future reference for anyone with the same problem, I'm going with it.

For future reference, setting up a custom editor with markitup was as easy as creating this settings hash:

```
var settings = {
  onShiftEnter:     {keepDefault:false, replaceWith:'<br />\n'},
  onCtrlEnter:      {keepDefault:false, openWith:'\n<p>', closeWith:'</p>'},
  onTab:            {keepDefault:false, replaceWith:'    '},
  markupSet:  [     
    {name:'Bold', key:'B', openWith:'(!(<strong>|!|<b>)!)', closeWith:'(!(</strong>|!|</b>)!)' },
    {name:'Italic', key:'I', openWith:'(!(<em>|!|<i>)!)', closeWith:'(!(</em>|!|</i>)!)'  },
    {name:'Stroke through', key:'S', openWith:'<del>', closeWith:'</del>' },
    {separator:'---------------' },
    {name:'Bulleted List', openWith:'    <li>', closeWith:'</li>', multiline:true, openBlockWith:'<ul>\n', closeBlockWith:'\n</ul>'},
    {name:'Numeric List', openWith:'    <li>', closeWith:'</li>', multiline:true, openBlockWith:'<ol>\n', closeBlockWith:'\n</ol>'},
    {separator:'---------------' },
    {name:'Picture', key:'P', replaceWith:'<img src="[![Source:!:http://]!]" alt="[![Alternative text]!]" />' },
    {name:'Link', key:'L', openWith:'<a href="[![Link:!:http://]!]"(!( title="[![Title]!]")!)>', closeWith:'</a>', placeHolder:'Your text to link...' },
    {separator:'---------------' },
    {name:'Clean', className:'clean', replaceWith:function(markitup) { return markitup.selection.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, "") } },       
    {name:'Preview', className:'preview',  call:'preview'}
  ]
}
```

Then just include the plugin script and it's associated stylesheets and add this line of javascript in an onDomReady:

```
$("#markItUp").markItUp(settings);
```

Comment: You should throw in a usage example in your answer.